# How to work with a streaming API with PHP

Tags: php, streaming, tradier

I am trying to use the Tradier streaming api to stream live quotes

I have tried using:

```
$chm = curl_init("https://api.tradier.com/v1/markets/events/session");
curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 "Accept: application/json",
 "Authorization: Bearer {MY SPECIAL TOKEN}",
));
curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer {MY SPECIAL TOKEN}"));
curl_setopt($chm, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$r = curl_exec($chm);
$ssid = json_decode($r)->stream->sessionid;

#up to here works
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"POST",
    'header'=> "Authorization: Bearer {MY SPECIAL TOKEN}"
  )
);
$default = stream_context_get_default($opts);
print_r(readfile('https://stream.tradier.com/v1/markets/events?symbols=SPY&sessionid='.$ssid));
fclose($default);
```

I want php to return data asynchronously while still listening in the stream

Right now it keeps on running forever till it reaches the time limit.

Answer (score -2):

I figured a way around the php streaming:

I do the streaming with python with a built in wrapper and upload that to a database

then I use ajax with php to update the screen based on the db's contents

Comment: eagle can you share you have code how you have implemented